# Where can i find public key of specific node on chef server?

Tags: chef-infra, private-key

As per docs, using chef-validator key chef-client creates a private key for node and public key and store the public key on chef-server. I would like to view public key of specific node on chef-server but couldn't find path/directory where public keys are stored on the chef server. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

They live in the Chef Server database so you can't see them directly. You can use `knife client show` to access them via the API though.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Actually I wanted to upgrade chef server 11 to chef 12 version. So i installed chef server 12 in different/new server and tried to test with copying one client info (node obj and public key) into new server and check if it is reporting properly. Is there a way I can copy database info from chef server 11 to new chef server 12.

Comment: You would copy everything via backup and restore and then use the upgrade process to move from 11 to 12.

Comment: Thanks!! Got that.